# Unity3D ScrollView dynamic width

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've got a ScrollView inside my Canvas which will be populated with a UI GameObject (Panel) at runtime. Because this dynamic child does not have a fixed size, I want to resize my ScrollView to the same width as the child. In other words: The ScrollView **should be the width of it's child**.

I think this is possible without the need of coding but I cannot get it to work properly.

I already tried to add a Content Size Fitter to the *Content*, *Viewport* and *ScrollView*, but this only results in a width of 0.

My structure is the following

[image: Example]

Please tell me if you need some more information

## Edit 1:

it seems like the problem is with the GameObject *Content*. It does not resize with it's child element

[image]

Comment: Layout is Unity is a bit complicated, but you can start by looking at Content Size Fitter. Theoretically it should do what you want, but it depends on a number of factors.

Comment: Should have mentioned that I tried it with Content Size Fitters but this results in a ScrollView whichs width is 0

Comment: It might help to put a Layout Element on your child. You need to populate "Preferred/Min Size" on your child.

Comment: you shouldn't make the content "stretch" in x and y direction than because this way it will always use anchors depending on the parent object instead of the child

Answer (score 1):

The only object that shouhld have ContentSizeFitter is the Content of the scrollview (only in the axis you want the content to expand). To work properly its best to also have a Vertical or Horizontal layout group, with checkboxes 'child control size' checked, and 'expand' un-checked. 
No all thats left to do is make sure all the children of the content object have LayoutElement with preferred layout sizes.

It can be a little bit tricky to get it right first few times but definitely possible. The order in which you add components is somewhat important : make sure you have layoutElements set up in the children first, then add the layout group, and only after it works correctly add the content size fitter. If you do it the other way around it tends to escape, as in you mnight get objects resized to 0 before you notice

Comment: But if I understand this correctly, the ScrollView will not autosize in it's width to fit it's childs width, does it?

Comment: scrollview crops the view using Mask, and is normally tied to the screen (you don't want the scrollview as an object to grow from users point of view). what you want to resize is scrollview's CONTENT, so that you have more to scroll the more content there is.